# Help with ISEE-3's historic L1 halo orbit's Spice kernels (1978-82); still available somewhere online?

Tags: jpl-horizons, halo-orbit

When I was looking for previous calculations for JUNO I [received help](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19263/12102) which pointed me [here](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/JUNO/kernels/spk/).

Now I'd like to review ISEE-3's orbit and compare it to calculations since receiving [this welcomed answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21910/12102).

When I go to Horizons, I can only get circa 2014-2016, the '[ISEE3 Reboot](https://www.facebook.com/ISEE3Reboot)'. I don't see ICE or ISEE-3 in the NAIF folders.

Is there some way I can get the 1978-82 timeframe Horizons orbit data (state vectors), either through Horizons, or at least the kernels, as I did [in this case](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19263/12102)?

Or, is there some standard way to request the data be reposted?

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't looked there before, the starting place for all NASA data is the NASA Space Science Data Coordinated Archive ([NSSDC](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov)).  Back in the day when I used to work with ISEE-3/ICE data, they were the place were you went to get your data or you sent it to archive your data.  I'm not familiar with the data format you are asking about, but the [orbital data page](https://spdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/data_orbits.html) is a good starting point.  Unfortunately, at the time of this writing, the NSSDC [Master Catalog](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/) is offline, so you might have to wait until it gets put back online.

Comment: Okay I'll keen an eye on those links. I'm certainly flexible about data format, I can try to interpolate, transform, fit with a dynamic model, etc. Thanks!