# Sources for SPICE Kernel (SPK) files for asteroids

Tags: asteroid, jpl-horizons

Besides the official source for SPK files (ftp://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/eph ...) is there a place where people upload kernels for the smaller bodies in the solar system? I was looking for the Jupiter Trojans and other Trojans.

Thanks!

Comment: You might find some information here slightly interesting, although it's not what you are asking for https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19263/12102 especially the "required reading" page https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/req/spk.html

Comment: Also, according to [this page](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?ephemerides), *Comets & Asteroids: Ephemerides for comets and asteroids are available from JPL's HORIZONS system. SPK ephemeris files can also be custom generated using HORIZONS for use with JPL's NAIF SPICE toolkit*.

Comment: Doesn't the DE438s have a bunch of them? The GM parameter for them is in the comments at the start (names start with `MA`), but I do not know if the Chebyshev coefficients are also present for these items.

Comment: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/asteroids/ and https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/x/spk.html may or may not be helpful

Comment: Ok, reporting back on all the helpful answers here: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/x/spk.html is great, gives SPK files, but a) only one body at a time b) the time range per file is heavily restricted - possibly for file size  c) hard to find what range of data is available for a body d) documentation issues e) which is probably why its not so findable (like no inbound links). The telnet interface to Horizons is possibly the ticket. I have to learn that and will report back.